# Different color on mesh's face towards to plane

Tags: javascript, three.js

I need to color a face looking towards to plane.

I thought two different approaches:

- Place a light source below plane (plane is only one sided) so down side of the object gets light color. But AFAIK I can only limit the light in PointLight, but my plane is rectangular. RectArea light looks good but does not work with my materials. Also I want my light to only affects some objects, not every object.
- Calculate facenormals for every object on every update, check them against plane normal; if its what I want color them using vertex/face colors. Also I need to paint every other to default color. But this seems to me too CPU heavy.

Is there any better way?

Comment: You can also use a custom shader for this. E.g. you can compute a color value based on the relation between the surface normals and the look/view direction. This should be the way more faster than computing vertex colors on the CPU per frame.

Comment: @Mugen87 Hmm, i didn't use shaders before. Also this is my first time in 3D space. Can you show me a some example or explain more? Thanks for your idea, btw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out by @Mugen87, the easiest way to achieve that is by using custom shaders.

This is a wide topic, it might take some getting used to. But the are incredible resources out there explaining this topic in-depth. [The Book of Shaders](https://thebookofshaders.com) is a good place to start.

---

By calculating the [dot product](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/dot.xhtml) between a surface normal and the inverse view direction, you can get information about how much a certain surface is "facing" towards the camera.

Using this information we can [mix](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/mix.xhtml) two colors and use that as the final color that will appear on the screen.

```html
<html>

<head>

<title> view-based color </title>

<style>
body { margin: 0; position: fixed;}
canvas { width: 100%; height: 100%; display: block;}
</style>

<script src="https://threejs.org/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://threejs.org/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<script>

var shader_vert = `

varying vec3 vNormal;

void main() {

 vNormal = normalize( modelMatrix * vec4( normal, 1.0 ) ).xyz;

 gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}

`;

var shader_frag = `

uniform vec3 viewDirection;

varying vec3 vNormal;

void main() {

 vec3 red = vec3( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
 vec3 pink = vec3( 1.0, 0.8, 0.8 );

 float q = clamp( dot( vNormal, -viewDirection ), 0.0, 1.0 );

 vec3 color = mix( red, pink, q );

 gl_FragColor = vec4( color, 1.0 );


}

`;

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.background = new THREE.Color( 0xffffff );
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );

camera.position.set( 0, 2, 5 );
camera.lookAt( new THREE.Vector3() );


// plane
var geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 2, 2, 2 );

// custom shader
var material = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
 uniforms: {
  viewDirection: { value: new THREE.Vector3() }
 },
 vertexShader: shader_vert,
 fragmentShader: shader_frag,
} );
var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
scene.add( plane );


window.addEventListener( 'resize', onResize );


function animate() {

 requestAnimationFrame( animate );

 plane.rotation.y += 0.01;
 plane.rotation.x += 0.01;

 camera.getWorldDirection( material.uniforms.viewDirection.value );

 renderer.render( scene, camera );

};

function onResize() {

 var w = window.innerWidth;
 var h = window.innerHeight;

 camera.aspect = w / h;
 camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

 renderer.setSize( w, h );

}

animate();

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Yes it works, I did use attribute normal and plane normal to calculate is it face towards to plane or not and color them. But the problem is when I rotate object, colors not getting updated. Maybe I need to recalculate normals? in where?

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing some code, but you probably need to pre-multiply `modelMatrix` to the normal vector, to account for object translation / rotation. If answer works, don't forget to mark as correct ;) cheers.

Comment: `vNormal = normalize((modelMatrix * vec4 (normal, 0.0)).xyz);`
I do calculate normals this way and it works now. Thanks for your help.